# Evaluating Expected Shortfall

Tags: validation, quantiles, finance

I am writing my thesis on VaR and ES risk measurements and have encountered some issues with how to best test the accuracy of ES statistics.

My understanding of the topic is that backtesting ES adequately is extremely difficult or even impossible, as it is not an elicitable risk measure. And I also assume the number of approaches in the literature are scarcity because of exactly this property.

However very recently D.Tasche et.al. (http://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.1645v2.pdf) uploaded a paper where it was argued that ES is not directly elicitable, but indirectly elicitable because it can be approximated by several VaR estimates. Thus, they state ES can be backtested reasonably by backtesting several VaRs (at different confidence levels) related to the ES estimate. Their specific proposition is:$E{S_\gamma }(L) = {1 \over {1 - \gamma }}\int_\gamma ^1 q u(L)du \approx {1 \over 4}\left( {{{\rm{q}}_\gamma }{\rm{(L)  +  }}{{\rm{q}}_{0.75\gamma  + 0.25}}(L) + {{\rm{q}}_{0.5\gamma  + 0.5}}(L) + {{\rm{q}}_{0.25\gamma  + 0.75}}(L)} \right)$

where L is the loss distribution and gamma the chosen confidence level.

From my simple calculations, proxying financial data with a student-t(6) the accumulated VaRs with this approach seems to deviate much from the analytical ES.

I wonder if anyone find the Tasche et.al. approach appealing/adequate for backtesting ES? Further I am also interested in knowing what the "state of the art" approach is in the industry (if any particular) for backtesting ES.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Such an approach can't work in general, though in many cases of practical interest it might yield a reasonable approximation. Do they give any solid theoretical backing for this?

Comment: They reason that ES per se is not elicitable, but it is composed of two elicitable components: the quantile ($c = {q_\alpha }(L)$) and the expectation conditionally on the quantile ($E\left[ {L|L \ge c} \right]$), hence they call ES "conditional elicitable". I do not get the intuition behind  ES integrated by several VaRs. They refer to [On the coherence of expected shortfall](http://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/0104295.pdf) Proposition 3.2, but that does not seem to help me understand it.